# Repair divider in wallet

Tags: restoration

I would like to repair or strengthen the divider in my wallet as shown here.

It kinda close quarters.

Part of the damage is caused when I close the zipper and catch the material.

[image: wallet]
*[Original image link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1nt39dj02ioicz/Wallet.png?dl=0)*

Comment: What material is it?

Comment: Fabric and I think the internal material may be plastic. @Erica

Answer (score 2):

It may not be pretty but...

I sewed the damaged material and used Gorilla glue to attach some leather pieces to both sides. The leather should protect it from the zipper rubbing against it.

[image]

Comment: Another approach would be to use iron on repair fabric, but folder over the top to give a good strong edge. Normally this is used to repair holes in jeans etc. It's normally available in at least blue, black and white, and just need a warm/hot iron.

Comment: Found this. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Iron-On-Patches-5-X5-2-Pkg-Black/23901326?wmlspartner=wmtlabs&adid=22222222222017282010&wmlspartner=wmtlabs&wl0=e&wl1=o&wl2=c&wl3=10356956149&wl4=pla-1103079622926&wl12=23901326_10000000249&wl14=black%20iron%20on%20patch&veh=sem&msclkid=cc62d53951ca1bdf5b1d899ca7ea3d7b